# Hibernate Configration file error

Tags: java, hibernate

I am new to hibernate framework. i made a sample project just to test hibernate. i set up the project. but when i run it i got this error

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: /hibernate.cfg.xml not found
at org.hibernate.util.ConfigHelper.getResourceAsStream(ConfigHelper.java:147)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.getConfigurationInputStream(Configuration.java:1405)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1427)
at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.configure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:972)
at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.configure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:69)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1414)
at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.configure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:966)
```

The **Hibernate.cfg.xml**  file that i put in the main package of the project.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
    <hibernate-configuration>

            <session-factory>
                <property name="hibernate.dialect">
          org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect
                </property>
                <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
                <property name="show_sql">true</property>
                <property name="connection.pool_size">2</property>
                <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>
       <!--<property name="htm2ddl.auto">create</property>-->
                <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">
          org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver
                </property>

       <!-- Assume test is the database name -->
                <property name="hibernate.connection.url">
          jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/NetworkDB
                </property>
                <property name="hibernate.connection.username">

                </property>
                <property name="hibernate.connection.password">

                </property>

       <!-- List of XML mapping files -->
       <!-- <mapping resource="Employee.hbm.xml"/>-->

            </session-factory>

    </hibernate-configuration>
```

I am using netbeans 7.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per DTD, `<hibernate-configuration>` should have a single `<session-factory>` but you have declared it twice.

Regarding second error:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: /hibernate.cfg.xml not found
```

Hibernate looks for the configuration file at the root of the classpath, so check if you have placed this file at root of your classpath.

So once you build your project the `hibernate.cfg.xml` file should be in classes directory.

Comment: I deleted one <session-factory> node but still getting this error

Comment: The error was same when i edited what you told. I add the <xml node at the top of the document too. now i am getting different error. please see my question i just edited it

Comment: It is in the root of class path. ->classes->com->example and there is this hibernate.cfg file along wiht HibernateTest.class where i write the code

Comment: you have placed it in wrong path, it should be in classes directory itself, not in subdirectory of classes. Also updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: now i put the confiuration file in the default package in the netbeans project. it's working now

Answer (score 1):

Add the following in first line of your xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

Comment: Now its a different question dude, your previous issue is resolved. Where have you placed your **cfg** file?

Comment: why have you marked negative for my answer?please give me a reason.